# Remote restore of DB in MSSQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, remote, database-restore

I have a remote MSSQL server meant to centralize SQL for development projects. I hand out DB's and access to developers as they need it. I do not want to give them access to filesystem in any way (would require RDP access or opening several firewalls).

My question is how can the developers *easily* copy their local DB to the remote DB as they transit from local databases to remote shared database?

For reference this is how you would do it in MySQL:
`mysql -h host -uuser -p db < db.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Management Studio Generate SQL scripts function (with Script data=TRUE - optional) on your database to generate SQL script, then run [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) utility with correspondent options to execute sql commands from specified script from local system on remote sql server(s).

To automate database script generation you can download and install [Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5498) - it can generate scripts for database schema and/or data